# Error when adding multiple files to Spring mime message

Tags: java, spring-boot, mime-message

Have a form that is emailed when user fills out and hits submit. There is also a modal on the form that "temporarily" saves files to a folder on the server. When the send form button is hit, I need for all of the files in the folder on the server to be attached to the form input email.

Tried using the FileSystemResource and helper.addAttachment in the email service file. Also tried setting the files as a variable to call upon, both ways are not working for me. I keep getting a java null pointer exception. Any idea how to add all files to the email as attachment or any idea what is going wrong?

Here is the controller for sending the form:

```html
@RequestMapping(value="/directBind",  params="send")
    public String send(Model model, @ModelAttribute(value="directBind") DirectBind directBind){
        List<String> businessAgencyList = directBind.getBusinessAgencyList();
        Mail mail = new Mail();
        mail.setFrom("no-reply@example.com");
        mail.setTo(new String[]{"example@example.com"});
        mail.setSubject("Data Checklist");

        Map<String, Object> mailModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        mail.setModel(mailModel);

        try {
            emailService.sendSimpleMessage(mail, directBind, storageService);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ("redirect:/?sentMessageFail");
        }
        return ("redirect:/?sentMessage");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/email")
    public String email(){
        return "emailMessage";
    }
}
```

Here is the email service

```html
public class EmailService {
   private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Autowired
    public EmailService(JavaMailSender javaMailSender){
        this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
    }

    @Autowired
    private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;
    
 public void sendSimpleMessage(Mail mail, DirectBind directBind, StorageService storage) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,
                MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED_RELATED,
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

        helper.addAttachment("Mail_Icon.png", new ClassPathResource("static/images/Mail_Icon.png"));

        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariables(mail.getModel());
        context.setVariable("directBind",directBind);
        String html = templateEngine.process("emailMessage", context);

        helper.setTo(mail.getTo());
        helper.setText(html, true);
        helper.setSubject(mail.getSubject());
        helper.setFrom(mail.getFrom());


        FileSystemResource file= new FileSystemResource(new File(storage.getUploadDir()));
        helper.addAttachment("attachment", file);

        javaMailSender.send(message);
    }
}
```